# How to set python version for running flask application in uwsgi?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, flask-socketio

I deployed a flask SocketIO application using uwsgi server in Ubuntu 16.04.I will be getting my original `app` instance from a script `wsgi.py`

```
from server import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

And in a separate virtual environment I installed all the dependencies required for my project and intended to run my application through a configuration file `myproject.ini` which will be activated by a service in `/etc/systemd/system`

Here's the configuaration file `myproject.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

And here's the `myproject.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/user/myproject/virtual_frame/bin"
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/virtual_frame/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run the application with the default wsgi server of flask then it's working fine

[image]

But, when I am trying to run the application with **uwsgi** server which I configured then I am getting the following error

[image]

As gevent doesn't work in `python3`, so I am assuming that the `uwsgi` server is running the application in `python3` enviroment

Therefore, I am interested to know the configuration to force uwsgi to work in `python` instead of `python3`

And here's the status of the project:-

[image]

Comment: are you using heruku? I have a working solution for that hosting platform

Comment: No. I am not using heroku.. I will be using my Ubuntu server for hosting. But, you could share your solution with hope

Comment: check it here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#supported-python-runtimes

Comment: and another useful ressource may be is here : https://forum.predix.io/articles/24718/how-to-specify-a-python-version-for-your-app.html

Comment: Did you look at the [Flask-SocketIO documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#uwsgi-web-server) with regards to how to deploy with uWSGI? You don't appear to be following that as a guide.